# Using $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{n}dx$ to show an equality

Tags: calculus

We know that $I_n = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2n+1}(x)dx = \dfrac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$ and $I_n = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2n}(x)dx = \dfrac{(2n)!)^2}{2^{2n}(n!)^2} \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, but how do we show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2^{4n}(n!)^4}{((2n)!)^2(2n+1)} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: just remark what is $(2n+1)I_1$ where $I_1$ is the first integral

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote $J_n=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2n}\!x\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x$ instead. As  $0\le \sin^{2n+2}x < \sin^{2n+1}x\le \sin^{2n}x$ on $\bigl(0,\frac\pi2\bigr]$, we deduce $\;0<J_{n+1}\le I_n\le J_n$, whence
$$0<\frac{J_{n+1}}{J_n}\le\frac{I_n}{J_n}\le 1$$
Furthermore, we have the recursion formula: $\;J_{n+1}=\dfrac{2n+1}{2n+2}J_n$, so
$$\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\le\frac{I_n}{J_n}\le 1$$
which proves $\;\dfrac{I_n}{J_n}$ tends to $1$ by the squeeze theorem. Now 
$$\dfrac{I_n}{J_n}= \dfrac{2^{4n}(n!)^4}{((2n)!)^2(2n+1)}\frac2\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

By [Wallis's product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) :$\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\cdot \frac{2n}{2n+1}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{4n}(n!)^4}{((2n)!)^2(2n+1)}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$$n!\sim a\sqrt{2n}\bigg(\frac{n}{e}\bigg)^n$$

Substituting for $n!$ yields:

$$\frac{\pi}{2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{4n}a^4(4n^2)n^{4n}e^{-4n}}{a^2(4n)2^{4n}n^{4n}e^{-4n}(2n+1)}\\=a^2\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2n+1}\\=\frac{a^2}{2}\\a=\sqrt{\pi}$$